# Add next line to string to be displayed in text view, android?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, textview

I have string value which comes from server in XML format.

For eg

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:Data="http://www.google.com">
<Data: Mesage="Dear Member,\\nWe wish you and your family a Very Happy New Year 2015./>
</rss?
```

Where \\n represents a new line. When I add "\n" to the string on server it becomes "\\n".

And it is displayed in textview as

```
Dear Member,\\nWe wish you and your family a Very Happy New Year 2015.
```

I am setting the text as

```
textview.setText(data_message.replaceAll("\\n", "\n"));
textview.setText(data_message.replaceAll("\\n",System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

I have tried both. But next line does'nt appears.

How do I add next line.

@almas

On using your code. The output I get is

```
Dear Member,\
We wish you and your family a Very Happy New Year 2015.
```

Comment: You should use `\\\\n` as the matching pattern. Remember that \\ results in \, so two backslashes, escaped, are \\\\.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the first param in replaceAll method, which also needs escaping.
This construction is ugly, but works correct:

```
    String text = "Dear Member,\\nWe wish you and your family a Very Happy New Year 2015.";
    textView.setText(text.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n"));
```

Comment: The text comes in next line but it leaves a "\"

Comment: Have you used exactly the same code? Because, it's strange - it works in theory, works in my device.. May be you have left one slash it message or add an extra one?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this,

```
  String text = "Dear Member,\\nWe wish you and your family a Very Happy New Year 2015.";
  textView.setText(text.replaceAll("\\\n", "/n"));
```

or

```
  String text = "Dear Member,\\nWe wish you and your family a Very Happy New Year 2015.";
  textView.setText(text.replaceAll("\\\n",System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) api as you are not using regex with your pattern as below:

```
String data_message = "Dear Member,\\nWe wish you and your family a Very Happy New Year 2015.";
System.out.println(data_message.replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator")));
Output:
Dear Member,
We wish you and your family a Very Happy New Year 2015.
```

Comment: It does works but the output I am getting is with a "\". Dear Member,\We wish you and your family a Very Happy New Year 2015.

Comment: Did you used single or double back slash "\\"? if twice update your code in question.

Comment: I am using double "\\"

Comment: Can you update your question with what you tried? It works for me so not sure why it wont for you?